# Redirect user to login before viewing custom post

Tags: users, redirect, login, content-restriction

I have a site with a listings page (https://gymkoi.com/class-listings/) and all I'm trying to do is redirect a user who is not logged in to my login page (https://gymkoi.com/login/) before they can view an individual listing.  If they are logged in then they can go straight to the individual listing.

I'd like to do this without having to use a plugin as this seems like it should be a relatively easy thing to do via php.

Thanks!

Comment: Quick question, after they login are they then directed to a page of listings or a specific listing?

Comment: eventually i'd like them to go to the listing they clicked on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up a child theme, and in the `single-listing.php` template, add conditions around the current code.

```
<?php
// If the user is not logged in, redirect
if ( false == is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
    exit;
}
// Else the user is logged in; show the listing
else {
    // Paste the regular template code here
}
?>
```

Everything else will remain public, while just the individual listings will force the user to be logged in before they can view the content. (This will also prevent search engines from seeing the content, so bear that in mind.)

Comment: This is great thanks!  One question (I'm a little new to php). How do I redirect to a custom login page vs the wp login page?  I think wp_login_url() is sending me to the wp login page.  How do I send them to https://gymkoi.com/login? Thanks so much!

Comment: That's correct - just replace `wp_login_url()` with `'/'` in quotes.

Comment: Better yet, add a login form right inside the `single-listing.php` for when a user is not logged in. `<?php wp_login_form(); ?>` - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_login_form/

Comment: thank you very much for the help, will test these out.